# Group column with another column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, powerpivot

I added a dynamic table to a sheet and I want to group two columns in another one. For example:

```
nm, lt, size
1, a, sm
1, b, lg
```

to be:

```
Columns nt-lt | colum size
nm   |   lt   |   size
1    |   a    |   sm
1    |   b    |   lg
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I just see a merged header

Comment: @agustin May you tell me how to do a merged header? I don't see that option

Comment: Comment added as answer because allows better markdown formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select both column headers.
2. Go to `Home` Tab and click on `Merge & Center` or follow these key sequence: <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>. Click `ok` in the alert popup.
3. Change the value of the new created merged cell.